# net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Could not load object from location : C:\.....\src\Formularios\Subreporte 1.jasper

Tags: java, path, jasper-reports

Error:

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Could not load object from
>   location : C:\Users\Juan Ortega\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Selección
>   de Aspirantes\src\Formularios\Subreporte 1.jasper

The folder where everything is saved is C:\Users\Juan Ortega\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Selección de Aspirantes. The subfolders and files inside are:

- build
- dist
- nbproject
- src

  - BD

    - ConexionMySQL.java
  - Formularios

    - Administrador.form
    - Administrador.java
    - Aspirantes.form
    - Aspirantes.java
    - Avisos.form
    - Avisos.java
    - ClaseiReport.java
    - Conexion.java
    - Principal.form
    - Principal.java
    - Reporte.jaasper
    - Reporte.jrxml
    - Subreporte 1.jasper
    - Subreporte 1.jrxml
    - Subreporte 2.jasper
    - Subreporte 2.jrxml
- build.xml
- manifest.mf
- MySQL Connector.jar

I clean and build the project so that other users can use it. When they run the generated Java executable file from the console, they get the error from above. The code inside the class `ClaseiReport.java` is the following:

```
public class ClaseiReport {
private Conexion con = new Conexion();

public void reporte() {
    JasperReport reporte;
    JasperPrint reporte_view;
    try {
        URL  in = this.getClass().getResource("Reporte.jasper");
        reporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(in);
        reporte_view = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, new HashMap(), con.getConnection());
        JasperViewer.viewReport(reporte_view,false);
        con.desconectar();
    }
    catch (JRException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I suppose the error is related with the full path on the file Reporte.jrxml:

```
<defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Users\\Juan
Ortega\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Selección de Aspirantes\\src\\Formularios\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
```

I don’t know how to ensure that the .jar finds the subreports when using it on a different computer. I have seen so many questions on forums with this error but I can’t figure out how to fix it.

The next block of code is contained on the main report (Reporte.jrxml). What should I change on the `<defaultValueExpression>` variable?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Reporte" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Users\\Juan Ortega\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Selección de Aspirantes\\src\\Formularios\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<queryString language="SQL">
    <![CDATA[SELECT * FROM datos WHERE ficha = (SELECT max(ficha)FROM datos)]]>
</queryString>
<field name="ficha" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="apellido1" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="apellido2" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="nombre" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="carrera" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<background>
    <band/>
</background>
<title>
    <band height="70">
        <frame>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="-20" y="-20" width="595" height="90" backcolor="#006699"/>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="20" y="30" width="555" height="43" forecolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[SUBSECRETARÍA DE EDUCACIÓN MEDIA SUPERIOR. DIRECCIÓN GENERAL DE EDUCACIÓN TECNOLÓGICA INDUSTRIAL]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </frame>
    </band>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="98">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="0" y="58" width="268" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#CCFFFF"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="14"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Clave de la Escuela: 18DCTO100F]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="268" y="58" width="287" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#CCFFFF"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="14"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Periodo:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <subreport>
            <reportElement x="327" y="58" width="228" height="20"/>
            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
            <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "Subreporte 1.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="11" width="555" height="36" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#CCFFFF"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[FICHA DE PRE-REGISTRO PARA EL EXAMEN DE INGRESO AL CETis 100]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <line>
            <reportElement x="0" y="88" width="555" height="1" forecolor="#CCFFFF"/>
        </line>
        <line>
            <reportElement x="0" y="93" width="555" height="1" forecolor="#CCCCCC"/>
        </line>
    </band>
</pageHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="425">
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement x="43" y="11" width="111" height="20"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Integer"><![CDATA[$F{ficha}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement x="138" y="41" width="115" height="20"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{apellido1}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement x="253" y="41" width="115" height="20"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{apellido2}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement x="368" y="41" width="115" height="20"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{nombre}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement x="113" y="71" width="255" height="20"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{carrera}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="11" width="43" height="20"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Ficha:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="41" width="138" height="20"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Nombre del Solicitante:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="71" width="113" height="20"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Carrera Solicitada:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="117" width="555" height="29" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFCC"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[*** Aviso ***]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <subreport>
            <reportElement x="0" y="156" width="555" height="250"/>
            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
            <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "Subreporte 2.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="266" width="555" height="29" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFCC"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[*** Recomendaciones ***]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="454" y="9" width="100" height="100" forecolor="#CCCCCC"/>
            <graphicElement>
                <pen lineStyle="Dashed"/>
            </graphicElement>
        </rectangle>
    </band>
</detail>
<columnFooter>
    <band/>
</columnFooter>
<pageFooter>
    <band height="17">
        <textField>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="4" width="515" height="13" backcolor="#E6E6E6"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Página "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" de"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField evaluationTime="Report">
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="515" y="4" width="40" height="13" backcolor="#E6E6E6"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
            <reportElement x="0" y="4" width="100" height="13"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.util.Date"><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</pageFooter>
<summary>
    <band/>
</summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: You should use a relative path instead. Are you including the folder Formularios in your jar file?

Comment: Yeah, I included it, but I don't know how to specify the relative path...

Comment: Sorry, was thinking about the issue being on the loading of the .jasper file from the code, but the issue lays on the code of the report itself (.jrxml). I think the best way to solve this would be to ship the reports on a folder at the same level of the jar file and not inside it, so you can refer the relative path from the report itself. In that case you could use as path just `./formularios/`.